# Android AppCompat 22.1.1 default text color and ActionMode style

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I am updating my application to use the version 22.1.1 of the Android Support Library. My application theme inherits from `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`.

It works fine, except that all texts are white if the `TextView` style is set to one of the [predefined style](http://www.google.com/design/spec/style/typography.html#typography-styles). So I end up with white texts on light background (default background color). With version 22.0.0, I had no issue.

I tried the follow in my theme, but it does not seem to work:

```xml
<item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
<item name="android:textColorPrimaryInverse">@color/black</item>
```

Moreover, the `ActionMode` now has a black background instead of white, as it used to be with 22.0.0.

Any idea on how to change this?

Comment: what theme you have passed to toolbar in layout?

Comment: I didn't set any theme to my `Toolbar` in layout. I was using the `theme` attribute of my theme to that. That was my mistake. Setting the `theme` directly on the `Toolbar` fixed the text color issue. The `ActionMode` is still dark thought.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was using the `theme` attribute in my theme to set the `Toolbar` theme. That's a mistake. The `Toolbar` theme has to be defined on the `Toolbar` tag directly.

For the `ActionMode` background color, it looks like I was taking profit of a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=160033) without knowing it.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out ! All my old projects working fine ! i have  changed from app:theme to android:theme , app:popupTheme to android:popupTheme  *android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
    android:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"*