# Change the default text color of appcompat-v7

Tags: android, android-appcompat

I recently changed the ActionBarSherlock library to AppCompat-v7, and the text color of my textviews is a little bit more "light-gray".

I would like to change the default textColor attribute of the library, and here is what I did in my custom theme:

```
<style name="Theme.myCustom" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/textColor</item>
</style>
```

...where textColor is #000000 (black)

But nothing has changed in my app.

What is the best way to change the default texts color ?

Comment: check: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29912260/android-appcompat-22-1-1-default-text-color-and-actionmode-style

Comment: and: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26870698/change-actionbar-title-text-color-using-light-darkactionbar-theme-in-appcompat-2

Comment: Why are simple things in Android so impossibly complicated?!!  This should just work out of the box....

Answer (score 1):

Please try `android:textColorPrimary` or `android:textColorSecondary`.

```
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/text_on_primary</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/subtitle_on_primary</item>
```

Sorry probably you need this.

```
android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary"
```

EDITED

Please try to use TextAppearance.

```
<style name="Theme" parent="@android:style/Theme"> 
<item name="textAppearanceSmall">@style/MyTextAppearanceSmall</item> 
</style> 
<style name="MyTextAppearanceSmall" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Small"> 
<item name="android:textColor">?colorPrimary</item> 


</style>
```

Comment: What is your activity theme?

Comment: My activity does not have a real "theme" but by default it should take the theme from <Application></Application> tag in the manifest which is "Theme.myCustom", which is itself inherited from @style/Theme.AppCompat.Light

Comment: Thanks. Did You add `android:textColor="?android:attr/textColorPrimary" ` to TextView layout?

Comment: I did not add this line because I really have a lot of textviews,  I am sure I can override the default color without adding a line on each my textviews...